# Manually trimming a string in Java (without String.trim())

Tags: java, string, trim

I was playing around with the idea of doing this without using `String.trim()`. I made a method that trims leading and trailing spaces, which is shown below:

```
public static String removeLeadingAndTrailingSpaces(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;

    while (s.charAt(i) == ' ') {
        i++;
    }

    for (; i < s.length(); i++) {
        sb.append(s.charAt(i));
    }

    // aux is the string with only leading spaces removed
    String aux = sb.toString();
    int j = aux.length() - 1;

    while (aux.charAt(j) == ' ') {
        j--;
    }

    // now both leading and trailing spaces have been removed
    String result = aux.substring(0, j + 1);

    return result;
}
```

I've tested it and it works 100%. But, I'm not convinced this is the most efficient or practical implementation. How else could I have done it? I feel it could be done without using the extra variables `aux` and `j`, but I couldn't come up with a way for it.

Comment: Have a look at the source code for String.trim(). Very efficient implementation there.

Comment: [Here's how it's implemented in the JDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.trim%28%29).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just examine `s` from the end to determine where the trailing white space starts and return a substring of `s`. No need for `sb` or `aux`:

```
public static String removeLeadingAndTrailingSpaces(String s) {
    int end = s.length();
    int i = 0;

    while (i < end && s.charAt(i) == ' ') {
        i++;
    }

    while (end > i && s.charAt(end - 1) == ' ') {
        end--;
    }

    return end> i ? s.substring(i, end) : "";
}
```

For a closer approximation to `trim()`, you'd want to check against all whitespace characters, not just `' '`.

Comment: To make it imitate `trim()`, just change `== ' '` to `<= ' '`

Comment: @4castle - Not really (or, perhaps, not really for a bug-free version of `trim()`). Using `<= ' '` doesn't work for various Unicode whitespace character codes like thin space (U+2009). A better solution would be to use `Character.isWhiteSpace()`.

Comment: I can't say that would be "better" because the [JDK uses `<= ' '`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.trim%28%29). It depends on what specification you want to use, the JDK's or your own.

Comment: @4castle - True. That's because the public API for `String.trim()` specifically says that the only characters it considers as white space are codes U+0020 and below. Since it's part of the API (since very early days of Java), we're stuck with it and implementations have to follow it. However, it's inconsistent with `Character.isWhitespace()` and, for many text handling applications, `String.trim()` is considered buggy.

Answer (score 0):

For removing spaces please use 
myString.replace(" ","");

Thanks and Regards,
Dilip D

Comment: That will remove all spaces, not just the leading and trailing ones like OP wants.